# Footer both fixed, and not covering content (without using explicit values)

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty sure this will be (correctly) marked as a duplicate, because it's a very basic and newbie question, but I can't find the answer o.O

What I want is a **fixed** footer, so I do this:

HTML:

```
<div class = 'content'>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>More and more content</p>
</div>

<footer>
    <p>footer.</p>  
</footer>
```

Style:

```
.content {
    color:green;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**But** this footer will "cover" my content, if the later is long enough. So I add 'margin-bottom:110px' to the .content, which ~equals to footer's height:

```
.content {
    margin-bottom: 110px;
}
```

And it "works". But I would like to avoid explicitly setting the .content's margin to any particular absolute value. Primarily because the footer's height varies from page to page.

Here is what I have now: https://jsfiddle.net/kpion/nmdsuca4/6/
clicking the "change footer size" shows what I mean.

Something like 
.content {margin-bottom: calc(footer.height + 10px)} would be exactly what I want, if it worked.

BTW, the javascript is there only to explain my issue, in reality I don't want to use javascript to achieve what I want.

BTW2: please bear in mind that I really want the footer to be **fixed**, i.e. always there, visible. So most solutions where we scroll down and *then* see it, is not what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `position: sticky` for the footer instead of `fixed`

check this:

```css
footer {
    background: red;
    opacity:0.4;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'content'>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <div id = 'test1wrap'>
    Works fine, but: 
    <button id = 'test1'>
      Change footer size
  </button>     
  </div> 
</div>
<footer>
  That's a footer.
</footer>
```

Comment: It... just works! Thank you, Adam! Hah, it's beautifully simple :)

Comment: You're welcome! glad to hear that helped. Just note that this solution is not support by IE11 and Opera mini. FYI @konrados

Comment: Well, I thought it doesn't :) No problem with that :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve following way using Flex, no need any position used:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.content {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
  overflow:auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
}
footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>More and more content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>More and more content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>More and more content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>More and more content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>More and more content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>More and more content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>More and more content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>More and more content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>More and more content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>More and more content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>More and more content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>More and more content 2018</p>
</div>

<footer>
    <p>Footer text<br /> Another Line</p>  
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There should be a way to accept more that one answers :) Actually, here it's pretty obvious, there should  be :) A different approach giving a bit different but still cool and wanted result :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fixed the footer and display content above it without needing to change opacity or hide some of contents i think this will work with you.

```js
let sel = (s)=>document.querySelector(s);

sel('#test1').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
 sel('footer').style.height = '200px';
  sel('#test1wrap').innerHTML += ' ...and now it covers content again';
})
```

```css
/*
I don't want the footer to cover the content. I would like to say - content: height - make it 'auto' plus height of the footer.

The trick with 'margin' works fine, but I don't want to to explicitly set it to an absolute value (here: 110px).

Also, if the footer's height increases, it again covers the contents.
*/

.con {
    height:75vh;
    color:green;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.content{
  height:75vh;
  width:calc(100% + 20px);
  overflow: auto;
}

footer {
    background: red;
    opacity:0.4;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20vh;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
<div class = 'content'>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <div id = 'test1wrap'>
    Works fine, but: 
    <button id = 'test1'>
      Change footer size
  </button>     
  </div> 
</div>
</div>
<footer>
  That's a footer.
</footer>
```